# how does Keys type work?

Tags: c#

I'm using `Keys` type to detect pressed keys.

At some place I do comparison like this:

```
if (keyData == Keys.Control)
//do something
```

where `keyData` is the key pressed of type Keys

However `keyData` contains

```
ControlKey | Control
```

So of course comparison doesn't work because `Keys.Control` contains only `Control`.

So what is the correct way to compare them?

Comment: What are you targeting? WinForm, Wpf ??

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it:

```
private void mainImage_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.LeftCtrl) // System.Windows.Input.Key
        LeftCtrlButtonIsPressed = true; // raise a flag
}
```